# Expected number of car honks

Tags: probability-theory

The number of times a professional car-driver sounds the horn while driving on any day is a random variable having the Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda $ . A two-day trip involving travel by car is arranged by hiring only one of the three professional car-drivers, for whom the values of are $20, 30$, and $40$, respectively. The car-driver is selected randomly with uniform probability. What is the expected number of times the horn is sounded during the trip?
My answer is 60 is it.
$$E(X)=2(\frac {30+40+20}{3})$$

Comment: That's the right answer.

Comment: Andre i have a question regarding my answer when i multiply by 2.Then doesnt it once again include the probability of choosing a driver which i have already done??

Comment: Well, I would have written it differently. The two day means are respectively $40$, $60$, $80$, so the expectation is $\frac{1}{3}(40+60+80)$. Still $60$.

Comment: Ohh i should have done this.Thanx

Comment: Your way is fine too, but the logic is perhaps clearer the other way.

Comment: You can get parentheses to adjust to the size of their content by using `\left` and `\right`.

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As discussed in the comments, your result is correct.